# Нормально ли соединять 4 запроса в 1 SQL?

Tags: объединение, sql

Нормально ли соединять 4 запроса в 1 SQL через INNER JOIN? Не будет ли всё тормозить из-за такого?

И вообще так делают?

Comment: Джойны вообще штука тяжёлая, лучше по отдельности выполняйте

Comment: @Алексей Скляр - бредятина... все зависит от слишком многих параметров - от структуры, наличия индексов, наличия сумм, группировок и т.д. а так огульно говорить - это верх непрофессионализма...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, делают.

Как правило, все, что можно сделать в базе - делают в базе, ибо она обрабатывает данные быстрее чем php, java и другие языки.

Советую попробовать и сравнить.

Comment: И, вы не поверите... Примерно год назад я тут написал так же, завязалась дискуссия, попробовали, проверили, и результат был не в мою пользу )

Проверяли на таблице где-то около 10М строк.

Comment: Тут вопрос в индексах... И в запросе... Ессно если загрузить всё в память и просто потом показывать - будет быстрее.

Comment: 2 @@Sasha121:

> она обрабатывает данные быстрее чем php, java и другие языки.

"код работает быстрее чем код" (субд это ведь тоже скомпилированный код) - абсолютно некоректное сравнение. БД заточена для роботы над множествами данных поэтому, обычно подобные действия выполняет быстрее OOTB

Comment: @Nofate, как Вы делали без INNER JOIN? Если не составит труда, приведите пример, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Чаще всего, один, пусть и большой составной запрос, работает быстрее, чем несколько отдельных. А вообще, в каждом отдельном случае, надо делать тестирование (**EXPLAIN SELECT**).

P.S. Кстати, почему бы вам не [пробежаться по данной статье](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/mysql-man-4.0-ru/mysql-optimisation.html)?